# want to connect to mysql from parallel desktop

Tags: mysql, parallel-processing

I wanna connect to mysql database which is on my Mac from parallel desktop(windows 11) ,but I can't. How can I connect to Mac IP from my parallel?

(I tried to  install mysql workbench on parallel but it says "your processor is not adequate). So, I had to install database on Mac.I also tried bridged wifi and using localhost but it can't find the database.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution for you.  I modified the MySQL Workbench installation to run on Mac ARM.  I also use USB Webserver to run a MySQL database on Windows ARM.  MAMP and WAMP don't seem to run on Windows with Parallels.

I too am trying to figure out how to access a database running on Mac from C# Windows Apps on Windows.  Have not had success yet.

You can get the install files for Workbench on my github page.

https://github.com/shadsluiter/MySQLWorkbenchM1MacParallels

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).